# Error when using Character.getNumericValue()

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

My code reads:

```
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)
    {

        char charValue = Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
```

Basically, I am trying to retrieve the numeric value of each item in my char Array, but I am receiving this error message when compiling:

```
incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
```

I am confused because I am not dealing with ints. I tried searching for a resolution to my specific problem but could not find an answer. Thanks ahead of time for any help you provide.

Comment: You can't understand Java unless you read the JavaDocs. What does the [JavaDoc say for your method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-)?

Comment: `Character.getNumericValue(char);` returns and `int`, so you have to either cast it like `char charValue = (char) Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);` or use integer type `int charValue = Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);`

Comment: @JamesKPolk I believe he understands what it does, it's just a matter of the type he wants to store his result in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're typing the charValue variable is a char when getNumerValue returns an integer.

set charValue type to int and try again.

Answer (score 0):

`Character.getNumericValue()` returns and `int`.

You have to either cast it like:

```
char charValue = (char) Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
```

or use integer type:

```
int charValue = Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
```

Make sure you understand what it does though, [it's JavaDoc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_getnumericvalue.htm) states that:

> The java.lang.Character.getNumericValue(char ch) returns the int value
>   that the specified Unicode character represents. For example, the
>   character '\u216C' (the roman numeral fifty) will return an int with a
>   value of 50.